# Adding and finding dynamically table Td

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my website, I dynamically add a table with `runat='server'` `td`s. I'm trying to use FindControl right afterwards, but it returns `null`. This is what I've tried:

```
myDiv.InnerHtml += "<td id='Td1' runat='server'></td>";
Control c = FindControl("Td1");
```

It won't find it and `c` will be `null`.

Comment: Not possible this way, why do you need it? Add a `TableCell` control to a `TableRow` which is added to a [`Table`'s `Rows`-collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), add this table to your div or better to a `Panel`..

Comment: I need it because I'm trying to add `asp:TextBox` into the `td` afterwards..

Comment: Add the `TextBox` to the avove mentioned `TableCell`, via `cell.Controls.Add(txt)`.

Comment: I did that, but still it won't find it using `FindControl` method..

Comment: It depends where the table is, if it's in a different `NamingContainer` as the page then you have to use that. Maybe you are also using a `MasterPage`, then it's `ContentPlaceHolder` is the `NamingContainer` and you have to use that(f.e. `ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("ID")`).